It seems to be in past
What can I use for "It seems to be" in the past?
E.g. It seems to be difference in these texts. (Present, unsure, difference still exists)
It seems ???(there was??) difference in these texts.(Past, unsure, there was a difference [but now the texts have no difference])

It seems to be difference in these texts isn't valid English. But that's because difference is a noun, where the context requires an adjective (different) - it's nothing to do with "past". What are you trying to say? Why do you want to include "seems to be" rather than "is"?

"He seemed to be sad yesterday, but he's happy now" uses Past Tense "seemed" for how he appeared yesterday. As opposed to "It seems he was sad yesterday, but he's happy now," which uses Present Tense because that's what the speaker thinks (or has become aware of) now (something the speaker now thinks about a past situation).

Thank you for correction. With adjective it becomes more interesting: a) Texts seem to be different; b) Texts seem to were(??) different? In both cases speaker speaks in present, but in case a) about texts which are probably different, in case b) about the texts which were probably different.

(b) The texts seem to have been different.
